# Cannot pass a parameter to the bot from web-chat in IE 11

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I have the webchat code to start the conversation. It works fine in Chrome but does not work in IE 11. On the bot side I want to read some initial data from the client in bot.on('conversationUpdate'). Where and how should I put my userID to be passed to the bot ?

Current client's code:

```
<script>
        window.fetch("https://xxxurladdress", { method: "POST" }) 
            .then(function (res) { return res.json(); }) 
            .then(function (json) { 
                const secret = json.secret;
                window.WebChat.renderWebChat({ 
                    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine(
{secret:secret }),
                    userID: "1588b0f6-50c3-416e-8970-1d86bad6c68b
                }, document.getElementById("webchat"));   
            document.querySelector("#webchat > *").focus(); 
         }); 

 </script>
```

bot code in bot.on('conversationUpdate'):

```js
bot.on('conversationUpdate', async function (message) {


        if ((message.membersAdded && message.membersAdded.length > 0
        && message.address.user.role !== undefined)) {

            let conversationId = message.address.conversation.id; 
            let userId = message.address.user.id;
```

bot cannot read the user.id in case of IE 11 while above code works fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for passing values to your backend in the Webchat is using `backchannel` feature.

There are great demos available on the Webchat's Github page here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event

In a few words, you should throw a custom event with all the data you need, and do not use the `conversationUpdate` event.

Then catch this event on your bot side, and here you are!

Comment: Thanks; I will try

Comment: I could not use as IE 11 syntax is completely different and I could not adopting the given code to make it working using https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1760 as window.simpleUpdateIn cannot be unsterstood by IE 11 ..

Comment: Did you add the script mentioned? `<script src="https://unpkg.com/simple-update-in/dist/simple-update-in.production.min.js"></script>`

Comment: yes; the problem was solved via different architecture at the end